# Accessing Firestore through reverse proxy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We need to identify all network traffic that a specific Android/iOS app induces. The app is using Firestore in the backend. By default, connections to Firestore always use the domain `firestore.googleapis.com` instead of a project-specific subdomain (like Cloud Functions do, for example). This way those connections can't be related to a specific app by only examining the outgoing or incoming network traffic of the device.

Is it possible to route the traffic through a proxy or similar to be able to identify connections uniquely?

```
 +-----+       +---------------+       +----------------------------+
 | App | ----> | Reverse Proxy | ----> | Firestore                  |
 |     | <---- | (mydomain.com)| <---- | (firestore.googleapis.com) |
 +-----+   ^   +---------------+       +----------------------------+
           |
           |
Connections that must be
 uniquely identifiable
  for a specific app
```

Is this possible with Firestore (at least, there's a function `setHost()` in the client SDK) and if so, what drawbacks would it have?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a reverse proxy server and install on it the **Firebase Emulator**. You can then connect to this server from your app. The emulator will receive your requests and redirect them to Firestore. This will give you some flexibility and achieve your use case to some extent. read more about the Firebase Emulator [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore)